# What difference does this much make here?

Tags: grammar

You are as like him as I am like Sarah.

You are as much like him as I am like Sarah.

What is the difference in meaning?

Comment: Do you really require the first *as*? *You are like him as I'm like Sarah.* Parse it like [You are like him] as [I'm like Sarah].

Comment: To make it sound poetic, I think *You are as much like him as I am like Sarah* is better. Some other possibilities are *You are as much like him as I to Sarah* or *You are no more like him than I to Sarah.*

Comment: You could. You could say it both ways, whichever way you'd like to say.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ah, that I learned here.

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, the first *as* is required.  It's a correlative construction (*as A as B*).  If A is negative, then the first *as* can optionally be replaced with *so* (*not so A as B*).

Comment: @snailplane so you agree that there is no difference in meaning between the two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

The two have the same meaning. The 'much' is optional, and not normally put in. You could use it here to make the sentence easier to understand if you wanted to, as I had to read it a couple of times to get the meaning.